# Not receiving a response from Dynamics CRM Server web Api

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-online

I am not getting a response from a Dynamics CRM web server, and was wondering if there is anything wrong with my below code. I am building a JSON payload and sending the request to a server using WEB API endpoint

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
    Uri requesturi = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/api/data/v8.2",url));
    httpClient.BaseAddress = requesturi;
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);  // 10 minutes
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, string.Format("/contacts",contact));                   
    request.Content = new StringContent(props.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage createResponse1 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    return createResponse1.StatusCode;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lower the following line.

Old

```
httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0); // 10 minutes
```

New

```
httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10); // 10 seconds
```

10 minutes is an amazingly long time to wait for request to complete. 30 seconds is an eternity for a web service request.

As you have specified such a long timeout if there is a transient error or lookup issue you will need to wait 10 minutes for it to timeout.

Chances are you will now get an error or exception from the code.